# Is it possible to find sum of this series?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations

I am trying to find the sum of the following series asked by my friend.
$$n\cdot\left(\bigl\lfloor\tfrac{n}{2}\bigr\rfloor+
\bigl\lfloor\tfrac{n}{3}\bigr\rfloor+
\bigl\lfloor\tfrac{n}{4}\bigr\rfloor+
\bigl\lfloor\tfrac{n}{5}\bigr\rfloor+
\cdots\right)$$
where the sum is up to $n/2$ terms if $n$ is even, and up to $(n-1)/2$ terms if $n$ is odd.

I am not getting how to solve it. Is this form can be reduced to a formula? Thank you.

Note: $\bigl\lfloor\;\;\bigr\rfloor$ means floor function, like $\bigl\lfloor 4.78\bigr\rfloor=4$.

Comment: What does `《...》` mean?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, what do you mean by "*$n/2$ terms*"?

Comment: M realy very sorry... plz have a look on updated quedtion

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikely to be a closed form.

A related function is called the [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) $$D(n)=\sum_{m\le n} d(m)=\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor $$  where $d(n)$ is the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), the number of positive integers which divide $n$.  Your function is $nD(n)-n = n\sum\limits_{m\le n} \big(d(m) -1\big)$.

Since $D(n) \approx n\log_e(n) + n(2\gamma-1)$, where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni%20constant), you might say your function was about $$n^2\big(\log_e(n) + 2\gamma-2\big)$$ though the absolute errors (positive or negative) can tend to grow faster than $n$ even if the relative error can tend to reduce: as an example, when $n=10079$ your function would give $850294677$ while the approximation would be about $850545092$, while for the highly composite $n=10080$ your function would jump up to $851094720$ while the approximation would be about $850723956$.